# Deleting a file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, native

I am developing a native android app using `HTML/CSS/JavaScript`. During the App flow, I need to permanently delete certain HTML files (stored locally). Can this be done?

I am a high school teacher trying to develop an educational app. I have basic knowledge of HTML/CSS and near zero knowledge of JavaScript!

Comment: By javascript you cant do this but by android you can do this.

Comment: Curious.... Why do you need to delete the files?

Comment: Native Android app is written in Java... not JavaScript, using HTML/CSS/JS you should try Cordova (PhoneGap) ot Ionic...

Comment: With JavaScript you can delete cached or downloded files. But all files that are in your .apk are just readable and not writable.

Answer (score 1):

modern broswer support javascript file operation but this file system is only in broswer and isolated from local files, refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File

if u do need delete file on android system, then u need your app provide a bridge to and call from js, run in app, in java code, delete the file
the code might look like

```js
JsBradge.delete(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript disigned as a web document script language, so it has many security essentials, such as absolute isolation in browser, which means no write acces to file system.
  So, you have two options - first is create your own bridge to java, for example call prompt('your_file_name'), catch it in java and delete your_file_name.
  Second - use any of mobile app framework, for example - Cordova.
  Sorry, but no easy ways =(